# Linear regression with ordinal scaled variables

Tags: categorical-data, least-squares, ordinal-data

A friend of mine is working on a problem set and asked me an interesting question: if we have 2 variables, which are ordinal scaled how to compute a linear regression with those?

$$x \in \{\text{empty, very_low, low, medium, 3/4 full, full}\}$$
and
$$y \in \{a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6 | a_i < a_{i+1}\}$$

Those are the results of a questionnaire, so we have over 10 000 pairs $(x_i, y_i)$
The question I was asked is how to use linear regression / multiple regression (OLS) to estimate y as DV from x as IV. I know that for linear regression or multiple linear regression the dependent variable has to be metric, for that reason I am a bit confused how to do this. I am also aware that x can be represented as a set of 5 dummy variables, but I still have no idea how to represent y. I think that the question is somehow messily stated, but it is still bothering me: is there is any way to do this using linear regression / multiple regression?